# What is the definition of a unbalanced bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

What is the definition of a unbalanced bipartite graph? From what i can read it is that the two disjoint set of vertices have different sizes [Is this true: any bipartite graph with unbalanced vertex parity is not Hamiltonian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275877/is-this-true-any-bipartite-graph-with-unbalanced-vertex-parity-is-not-hamiltoni), but cant find a formal definition.

Comment: A bipartite graph with partition classes $V_1$ and $V_2$ is called unbalanced if $|V_1|\neq|V_2|$.
Isn't this a formal definition?

Comment: I guess it is then, thanks!